# Linux kernel icmp_reply

Tags: linux, kernel

Where can I find the explaination about corresponding function in linux kernel, especially for `ICMPv4`?

For example: `icmp_reply`, `icmp_send` and etc.

Thanks for helping.

Best,
Alim

Answer (score 1):

A good starting point for exploring ICMP code in Linux kernel is to peek into files `net/ipv4/icmp.c` and `net/ipv6/icmp.c` in Linux kernel source tree.

You can find relevant files from the source tree with various ways, easiest being to finding files by filename, e.g. with `find /your/kernel/source/dir -name "*icmp*" -print` will print out a list of files having string "icmp" in their filename. Another way would be to run something like `find /your/kernel/source/dir type f -name "*.c" -exec grep -l icmp {} \;` which would search for all C source files and display names of those which contain string "icmp". You can find more examples of how to use things like grep and find from more appropriate Stack Exchange sites like Unix & Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You can search here [code-grep.com linux lxr](https://code-grep.com/view/project/54b083273b2082684a000008/linux-3.19-rc2)

For example, icmp_reply:

https://code-grep.com/view/project/54b083273b2082684a000008/linux-3.19-rc2?search=icmp_reply&type=definitions&page=0

Answer (score 0):

Another important way is to observe the git history of some file.
This way you can read in twitter-like style all
the changes with full explanation.

For example:

```
$ git clone https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git
$ cd linux-stable
$ git log --full-diff -p ./net/ipv4/icmp.c
```

Then search in this git history by pressing the slash ("/") and typing "icmp-reply".

Answer (score 0):

ICMP supports a set of /proc interfaces to configure some global IP parameters.  The parameters can be accessed by reading or writing files in the directory /proc/sys/net/ipv4/.  Most of these parameters are rate limitations for specific ICMP types.  Linux 2.2 uses a token bucket filter to limit ICMPs.  The value is the timeout in jiffies until the token bucket filter is cleared after a burst.  A jiffy is a system dependent unit, usually 10ms on i386 and about 1ms on alpha and ia64. Follow up this link for more details

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/icmp.7.html